# Smart contract deployment to testrpc

Tags: java, ethereum, smartcontracts

I have a contract which compiles and the functionalities have been tested. I am deploying it on testrpc (using web3j) however I'm getting an `invalid opcode` error.

I thought it was not so important as testrpc was outputing `Contract created`

```
Transaction: 0xee46dd1227638b29dc1e9675b84bace7c38ae8c77b6b36e730e3475dde25da9e
Contract created: 0xc09fc91f653dac6a22c940edec4786f2ac7885c6
Gas usage: 0x47e7c4
Block Number: 0x03
Block Time: Fri Jun 16 2017 13:39:45 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Runtime Error: invalid opcode
```

Loading the contract did not output any exception however I can't get any functionality to work. Could anyone help me understand what happened ? Is the contract actually on testrpc ? I'd be interested in any information you could give me.

```
public void deployStreak() {
  try {
    contract = Streak.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, INITIAL_WEI).get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

EDIT:
The contract is wrapped using web3j's wrapper (auto-generated). My implementation to interact with the wrapper is as follow (slightly simplified).

```
public class EthereumApi {

private static final String INFURA_MAIN_NODE = "https://mainnet.infura.io/xxx";
private static final String INFURA_TEST_NODE = "https://ropsten.infura.io/xxx";

private static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = new BigInteger("100000000000");
private static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = new BigInteger("4712388");
private static final BigInteger INITIAL_WEI = new BigInteger("1");
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "a60931fc499e82b283b4406bef947e6d74d3a3ff3de6a51e3da4aacc17286723";

private static final boolean DEV_MODE = true;

private static EthereumApi instance = null;
private Web3j web3j;
private Streak contract = null;
private String contractAddress = "0x5879b9d58fd0e033c3114c5ab1d4228485708537";
private Credentials credentials;

private EthereumApi() {
  if(DEV_MODE) {
    web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
    System.out.println("[ETH-INFO] Connected to TestRPC");
  } else {
    web3j = Web3j.build(new InfuraHttpService(INFURA_TEST_NODE));
    System.out.println("[ETH-INFO] Connected to Infura Node on Ropsten...");
  }
  credentials = Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY);
  System.out.println("Credentials: " + credentials.getAddress());
}

/**
 * Singleton to access the API instance
 */
public static EthereumApi getInstance() {
  if(instance == null) {
    instance = new EthereumApi();
  }
  return instance;
}

/**
 * Delete instance of the API
 */
public void close() {
  instance = null;
}

public String getClientVersion() {
  String version = null;
  try {
    version = web3j.web3ClientVersion().sendAsync().get().getWeb3ClientVersion();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   this.close();
  }

  return version;
}

/**
 * Sends `amount` ether from the main account to `address`
 */
public void sendEth(String address, Long amount) {
  try {
    TransactionReceipt receipt = Transfer.sendFunds(
    web3j, credentials, address, BigDecimal.valueOf(amount), Convert.Unit.ETHER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      this.close();
    }
 }

public void deployStreak() {
  try {
    contract = Streak.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, INITIAL_WEI).get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void loadStreak() {
  try {
    contract = Streak.load(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void loadStreak(String address) {
  try {
    contract = Streak.load(address, web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have it on Github? How do you run it through Java?

Comment: I've added my java interface, thanks for the help